# Process synchronization with semaphores

Tags: concurrency

This was an interview question , any help would be appreciated

How do you synchronize two processes, out of which one is increments a value and the the displays it ( P.S. the process which displays the value must only display a value when its a new value )

Ex : int x = 5;
P1 : increments it to 6
P2 : must display 6 ( only once ) and must display it again when it becomes 7

I answered that I would use a semaphore something like

```
int c=0; // variable that I used to synchronize


// In P1
if( c = 0 )
{
   c++;
   x++; // value that is incremented
}

// in P2
if( c == 1 )
{
   cout<<x;
   c--;
}
```

He then asked what would you do if there's a context switch from process P1 to P2 after setting c to 1 but before incrementing x ( As in that case it would enter P2 before incrementing x )

I couldn't answer this part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution in python, 2 semaphores will be needed.
Note that this is a solution for a single producer/printer, in case you needed multiple producers / writers it wouldn't work

```
   from threading import Semaphore, Thread

    x = 0
    ITERS = 10


    def producer():
        global x
        while x < ITERS:
            s_empty.acquire()
            x += 1
            s_full.release()


    def printer():
        while x < ITERS:
            s_full.acquire()
            print(x)
            s_empty.release()


    s_empty = Semaphore(1)
    s_full = Semaphore(0)

    t1 = Thread(target=producer)
    t2 = Thread(target=printer)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: In the above case, even if I change the order it will still be erroneous as in this case value might get incremented twice if context switch happens just after x++ operation but before c++ operation

Comment: No, because P2 won't be able to proceed until c is changed to 1

Comment: Yes but it will enter P1 and x will be incremented again

Comment: Is it pseudocode? What do the ops c == 0 / c == 1 correspond to? Is it blocking?

Comment: Yes it is blocking

Comment: Updated my answer to real code, misread your original question

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me why you set s_empty to 1 and s_full to 0

Comment: The printer won't do anything until there's something to print because the s_full is initially 0 and it's unable to acquire it